# Loading csv file to GreenPlum failed on java

Tags: java, postgresql, csv, jdbc, greenplum

I'm trying to import a csv file to GreenPlum DB,

It's working with the following command from psql console (9.4.0, server 8.2.15)

```
\COPY data."TableName" FROM 'D:/Document.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

But fails when I tried to it from my java code:

```
public boolean InsertFile(Path tempFile, FileDetails file) {
   try{
       Connection conn =  GetConnectionString();

       String cmd = "\\COPY data.\"TableName\" FROM 'D:/Document.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;";

       Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       int res = st.executeUpdate(selectCmd);

       conn.close();
       return true;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       return false;
   }
}
```

The exception is syntax error because of the backslash (\)

Comment: Can you post the error here?

Answer (score 0):

COPY comes in two separate variants, COPY and \COPY: COPY is server based, \COPY is client based. If you just try COPY without the backslash, it should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54380/gpadmin";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user","gpadmin");
    props.setProperty("password","changeme");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

    String cmd = "COPY timeout FROM '/tmp/timeout.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;";

    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    int res = st.executeUpdate(cmd);
    System.out.println(res);

    conn.close();
}
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means I need to upload the file to the server which I wanted to avoid.